# Display every nth value on discrete axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

How I can automate displaying only 1 in every n values on a discrete axis?

I can get every other value like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

my_breaks <- function(x, n = 2) {
  return(x[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, n - 1))])
}

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = my_breaks)
```

But I don't think it's possible to specify the `n` parameter to `my_breaks`, is it?

Is this possible another way? I'm looking for a solution that works for both character and factor columns.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not quite like that, but `scale_x_discrete` can take a function as the breaks argument, so you we just need to adapt your code to make it a *functional*  (a function that returns a function) and things will work:

```
every_nth = function(n) {
  return(function(x) {x[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, n - 1))]})
}

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = every_nth(n = 3))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's a really neat solution!

Comment: This is highly appreciated

Answer (score 15):

Since ggplot 3.3.0 it is also possible to solve the problem of dense labels on discrete axis by using `scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))`, which gives (figure from documentation):

[image]

See the [rewrite of axis code](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#rewrite-of-axis-code) section of the release notes for more details.