# Control Discrete Tick Labels in ggplot2 (scale_x_discrete)

Tags: r, ggplot2

On a continuous scale, I can reduce the density of the tick labels using `breaks` and get nice control over their density in a flexible fashion using `scales::pretty_breaks()`. However, I can't figure out how to achieve something similar with a discrete scale. Specifically, if my discrete labels are `letters`, then let's say that I want to show every other one to clean up the graph. Is there an easy, systematic way to do this?

I have a hack that works (see below) but looking for something more automatic and elegant.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# make some dummy data
dat <-
  matrix(sample(100),
         nrow = 10,
         dimnames = list(letters[1:10], LETTERS[1:10])) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("row") %>%
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "column", values_to = "value")

# default plot has all labels on discrete axes
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(row, column)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
```

[image]

```r
# desired plot would look like following:
ylabs <- LETTERS[1:10][c(T, NA)] %>% replace_na("")
xlabs <- letters[1:10][c(T, NA)] %>% replace_na("")

# can force desired axis text density but it's an ugly hack
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(row, column)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = ylabs) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = xlabs)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option for dealing with overly-dense axis labels is to use `n.dodge`:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(row, column)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  scale_y_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

[image: ggplot with dodging axis labels]

Alternatively, if you are looking for a way to reduce your use of `xlabs` and do it more programmatically, then we can pass a function to `scale_x_discrete(breaks=)`:

```r
everyother <- function(x) x[seq_along(x) %% 2 == 0]
ggplot(dat, aes(row, column)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = everyother) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = everyother)
```

[image: ggplot with alternating label removal]

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! For compactness, I went with a [lambda](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_function.html) function: `scale_x_discrete(breaks = ~.[c(T, F)])`

Comment: Nice code-golf, and I had forgotten that `scale_*` takes rlang-style functions.

Comment: may I ask, where is "everyother" from? see also Gregor Thomas answer in this thread for a more general function https://stackoverflow.com/a/52920047/7941188

Comment: It's a custom function defined in the second code block. But the answer you link is a very good one, thanks for sharing it!

Comment: @DanAdams thanks - I have overlooked this line :)